# Using Having(count()) with CIs active record

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have the following SQL query but I can't seem to find out how I would change this query to make it work with CI:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table2.tID = Table1.tID
JOIN Table3 ON Table3.vID = Table2.vID
WHERE vegetable
IN (
'Potatoe', 'Carrot'
)
GROUP BY Table1.tID
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT vegetable ) =2
```

Here is what I have so far on CI:

```
$arrCount = count($array);
$this->db->select('*');
this->db->from('Table1');
$this->db->join('Table2', 'Table2.tID = Table1.tID'); 
$this->db->join('Table3', 'Table3.vID = Table2.vID');
$this->db->where_in('vegetable', $array);
$this->db->group_by("Table1.tID");
$this->db->having('vegetable');
$this->db->count_all($arrCount);
$q = $this->db->get();
```

But doing this gives me the following sql statement:

```
Table 'DatabaseTest.2' doesn't exist

SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM `2`
```

I am pretty sure the ActiveRecord count I have used is incorrect but I am not sure what else it would be because I have found any `COUNT()` function with CI.

So my question is how can I make my SQL query in CodeIgniter?

Extra note, I have also tried running the query using CIs `$this->db->query` but get an array error, when looking with the `in`.

```
$this->db->query('SELECT *
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table2.tID = Table1.tID
JOIN Table3 ON Table3.vID = Table2.vID
WHERE vegetables
IN (
' .$array . '
)
GROUP BY Table1.tID
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT vegetables ) =' . $arrCount);
```

And heres the error message:

```
Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
```

So it is assuming that I am using a `where` instead of a `where in` it looks like. Again can someone help me get my sql to work with CIs active record?

Comment: the $array should be imploded!

Comment: You shoud use double quotes for variable parsing.

Comment: I don't undestand. What is `DatabaseTest.2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested the first query with active records, but wouldn't this work? count_all is a query of on it's own. The first parameter is suppose to be the table... you entered the size of your array as the table which is 2!!! [active records reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

```
$arrCount = sizeof($array);
$this->db->select('*');
this->db->from('Table1');
$this->db->join('Table2', 'Table2.tID = Table1.tID'); 
$this->db->join('Table3', 'Table3.vID = Table2.vID');
$this->db->where_in('vegetable', $array);
$this->db->group_by("Table1.tID");
$this->db->having('COUNT(DISTINCT vegetable)', $arrCount);
$q = $this->db->get();
```

Also, for the query, you need to convert your array into a string:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT *
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table2.tID = Table1.tID
JOIN Table3 ON Table3.vID = Table2.vID
WHERE vegetables
IN (
' .implode(',',$array) . '
)
GROUP BY Table1.tID
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT vegetables ) =' . $arrCount);
```

Comment: The active record method does not fully work, but if you change the following line to this `$this->db->having('COUNT(DISTINCT vegetable) =', $arrCount);` it seems to work as expected. Thanks. Edit: Looks as though you had already changed your code before I wrote this =P

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->query('SELECT *
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table2.tID = Table1.tID
JOIN Table3 ON Table3.vID = Table2.vID
WHERE vegetables
IN ("' . implode('", "', $array) . '")'
GROUP BY Table1.tID
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT vegetables ) =' . $arrCount);
```

Use implode() to turn your array into a MySQL readable string.

**EDIT: Implode with quotes.**

Comment: This almost works I am just wondering when I implode is it possible to get the imploded values with and apostrophe around it? Because without it I get an error as it assumes I am looking in a column instead of a value.

Comment: You mean you want to do this? "apple; banana; grape; "

Comment: More like `'apple','banana','grape'` right now its coming out like this instead `apple,banana,grape`

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest get **$this->db->count_all($arrCount);** line away, at less until you get this working.